# Onde estão minhas perguntas marcadas como favoritas?

Tags: suporte, favoritos

Estava dando uma olhada nas perguntas do  site eu gostei de várias. Daí fui marcando algumas como favorita clicando na estrelinha!

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu ver todas as minhas perguntas marcadas como favoritas?

Comment: Teoricamente é nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/106738/danilo-rodrigues?tab=favorites mas não tem nada relacionado lá, você estava logado nessa conta quando favoritou?

Comment: eu tava logado em outra conta .
mais valew pela dica  eu pode ver  aki...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pelo [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) a seguinte consulta retorna todas as suas perguntas que algum usuário marcou como favorita. A última conluna apenas monta o link com o id da questão e o id do usuário.

Não esqueça de mudar o valor de `OwnerUserId` com o seu id.

```
SELECT id, title, favoritecount, concat('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/', id, '/',OwnerUserId) as link
FROM posts 
WHERE OwnerUserId = 91 AND FavoriteCount >= 1
```

A saída é algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 10):

Tem como ver sim, basta ir no seu link de "Perguntas" no seu perfil.

Repare que as suas perguntas que foram favoritadas ganham um estrelinha a esquerda com o número. (penúltima pergunta da imagem)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que também quando vc entra na sua pergunta a mesma estrala aparece logo abaixo das setas para votar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Já as perguntas que Você marcou como favoritas vc pode ver acessando entrando no seu Perfil, depois vai na Aba Participação e escolha a Aba Favoritos. Lá tem as perguntas que [você marcou como suas favoritas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/106738/danilo-rodrigues?tab=favorites).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer usuário pode ver as questões favoritas dos demais. O formato geral do link que abre essa informação é:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<user-id>/<user-name>?tab=favorites
```